# Stacked overlaid bar with data unchanged

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to make a stacked barplot with the data unchanged. I mean, I have already calculated the percentages to plot. According to the ggplot2 manual "geom_col uses stat_identity: it leaves the data as is". However, looks like it isn't working as the percents of the plot are different from that of the sample data.

Download sample data from [here](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0B9eRIc-w3cjVX2x2Vy1IRnhPNUk&export=download).

Code is as follows:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Pathway, y = value, fill = variable)) +
        scale_fill_manual(values=c("#005588", "#E69F00")) +                                                             
        #stat_identity(geom="bar", width=0.5) +                                                                                                                    
        geom_col(width=0.5) +
        #geom_bar(stat="identity", width=0.5) +
        facet_grid(. ~ Timepoint) +
        coord_flip() +
        theme_bw()
```

[image: geom_col changes data and rows order]

On the other side, If I use the option "stat_identity" the data remains unchanged (compare percents from both images with sample data), but the bar plots are not stacked any more.

[image: stat_identity do not touch the data but looses stacked bars.]

Is the "geom_col" option not working or am I doing something wrong? Should I use another plot method? Any help is appreciated.

dput:

```
structure(list(Pathway = c("Antigen Presentation Pathway", "Graft-versus-  Host Disease Signaling", 
"T Helper Cell Differentiation", "Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
"Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells", "Antigen Presentation Pathway", 
"Graft-versus-Host Disease Signaling", "T Helper Cell Differentiation", 
"Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
"Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells", "Antigen Presentation Pathway", 
"Graft-versus-Host Disease Signaling", "T Helper Cell Differentiation", 
"Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
 "Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells", "Antigen Presentation Pathway", 
"Graft-versus-Host Disease Signaling", "T Helper Cell Differentiation", 
"Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
"Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells", "Antigen Presentation Pathway", 
"Graft-versus-Host Disease Signaling", "T Helper Cell Differentiation", 
"Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
"Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells", "Antigen Presentation Pathway", 
"Graft-versus-Host Disease Signaling", "T Helper Cell Differentiation", 
"Cytotoxic T Lymphocyte-mediated Apoptosis of Target Cells", 
"Communication between Innate and Adaptive Immune Cells"), Timepoint = c("15DPI", 
"15DPI", "15DPI", "15DPI", "15DPI", "30DPI", "30DPI", "30DPI", 
"30DPI", "30DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", 
"15DPI", "15DPI", "15DPI", "15DPI", "15DPI", "30DPI", "30DPI", 
"30DPI", "30DPI", "30DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", "45DPI", 
"45DPI"), variable = c("Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", 
"Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", 
"Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "Targets", "DEGs", 
"DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", 
"DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs", "DEGs"), value = c(2.63157894736842, 
4.16666666666667, 1.36986301369863, 3.125, 1.12359550561798, 
7.89473684210526, 18.75, 8.21917808219178, 18.75, 7.86516853932584, 
15.7894736842105, 16.6666666666667, 10.958904109589, 9.375, 8.98876404494382, 
44.7368421052632, 35.4166666666667, 43.8356164383562, 37.5, 31.4606741573034, 
47.3684210526316, 43.75, 42.4657534246575, 37.5, 33.7078651685393, 
52.6315789473684, 39.5833333333333, 39.7260273972603, 31.25, 31.4606741573034)), .Names = c("Pathway", "Timepoint", "variable", 
"value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

Comment: What is your expected output? the code you posted appears to be working for me

Comment: Stacking bars is different than "leaving things as they are". You want the default `position = 'stack'`, not the custom 'position 'identity'` you are using.

Comment: @Mike H I need the original percents from the sample data, like in the second plot, but stacked like the first plot.

Comment: I don't want to download any files and read stuff in. Can you share a small sample of data that illustrates the problem? The data you `dput` isn't helpful because it has only one value of `variable`, only one row in the second `Timepoint`, and all unique values of `Pathway`, so there's nothing to stack. 8 rows (2 timepoints * 2 pathways * 2 variables) should be sufficient.

Comment: @fred maybe it's just me, but is that not what the first plot is doing? The second plot is showing the `DEGs` only (which cover the `Targets`). The second looks to be stacking the percents from the `DEGs` and the `Targets`

Comment: @ Gregor: Have a look now.

Comment: @Mike: If you compare the x-scales from both plots you gonna see that they are different. Look at the second pathway in the first plot. There isn't such percentage in the data. Looks like it's been recalculated somehow.

Comment: When you say *"I have already calculated the percentages to plot"* do you mean that you do not want `ggplot` to stack the bars? Like, if you have values `5` and `20` in you want the bars plotted up to `5` and `20` rather than `5` and `25`? That would be **not** stacking, `position = 'identity'`. Stacking means "one bar starts where another bar stops". It sounds like you just want "one bar overplotted on the other".

Comment: @Gregor: You are right! I want "one bar overplotted on the other".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the discussion by you and Gregor in the comments above, it sounds like you do not want the plots stacked on each other, but rather overlaid. I believe this should work for you:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Pathway, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#005588", "#E69F00")) +                                                             
  geom_col(width = 0.5, alpha = 0.5, position = "identity") +
  facet_grid(. ~ Timepoint) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

I use `position = "identity"` to make sure the bars don't stack. I also had to make the bars transparent with `alpha = 0.5` so you can see them.

---

Another option if you want to have them plotted side by side instead of stacking is to use `position = "dodge"`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x = Pathway, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#005588", "#E69F00")) +                                                             
  geom_col(width=0.5, position = "dodge") +
  facet_grid(. ~ Timepoint) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]